# How to organize sequence of data processors with .net RX

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

What is the best way to organize sequence of data processors with .net RX?
  - a. Call methods on observable like  `observable.Do(log).Select(transformation).Do(work).Aggregate(someState)...`
  - b. Implement custom observers, if so - how to chain them
  - c. Other option.. And also what is the    best option to handle possible exceptions in observable itself (see      my concerns above) and to handle exceptions inside Do, Select, etc       (as I know the best practice is that Subscribers shouldn't throw).

Also I need sometimes to allow exceptions being returned as some elements of observable sequence without sequence being stopped (see this question [Handling Exceptions in Reactive Extensions without stopping sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13310557/296494))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like you need a workflow instead of Rx. It seems based on your other questions* you are trying to take what looks very well suited to a ProducerConsumer queuing workflow scenario, and forcing it into Rx.

It looks like you

- want to Read from a Queue and block until a value is received, then
  resubscribe. Just use  Queuing features of BlockingCollection. As values arrive they can be pushed into the collection from any thread.
- dont want to actually have a sequence of values, but a workflow that can
  fail on any given value, divert that and then process the next value.
  Just use a queue. Process each value and put the results into the next appropriate queue
  (Failure/Success) ->See [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/),
  specifically Invalid Message Channel and Dead Letter channel.
- potentially process these values in parallel. See
  BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable or the [Disruptor](https://github.com/odeheurles/Disruptor-net) for a
  high performance implementation. With these tools you can have many produces and consumers. Sure you can do this with Rx, but it is just polling and tying up a thread doing so. I think it is better to be explicit about this kind of thing

I think your usage of Rx should pay for itself and you shouldn't find yourself fighting it (like any other technology or framework).

*other questions like 
[Handling Exceptions in Reactive Extensions without stopping sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310557/handling-exceptions-in-reactive-extensions-without-stopping-sequence)
and 
[How to serialize Observables to the cloud and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311386/how-to-serialize-observables-to-the-cloud-and-back)