# How to serialize Observables to the cloud and back

Tags: c#, serialization, system.reactive, azure-storage-queues, azure-servicebus-queues

I need to split processing sequence (like in this question [How to organize sequence of data processors with .net RX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13310865/296494)) into several computation units in Azure environment.
The idea is to serialize Observable sequence to Azure Queues(or Service Bus) and to deserialize it back.
If producer or consumer is failed other party should be able to continue producing/consuming.

Could anyone suggest an elegant way to do so and what to use (Azure Queues or Service Bus)?
Has anyone used TCP Observable provider - http://rxx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TCP%20Qbservable%20Provider for such problems is it safe to the failures of one of the parties?

Comment: Can you rename this question? It appears that you are not asking how to serialize an observable sequence (which makes me think you want to serialize the query--> IQbservable), but the values of an observable sequence. Too pendantic? On a side note, I think reading/writing from Queues is far better suited to IEnumerable anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have a messaage queue with the following API

```
class MQ {

    public MQ();

    // send a single message from your message queue
    public void send(string keyPath, string msg);

    // Receive a single message from your message queue
    public async Task<string> receive(keyPath);

}
```

To make this RX compatible

```
class MQRX: IObserver<string> {
    MQ _mq;
    string _keyPath

    MQRX(string keyPath){
        _mq = mq;
        _keyPath = keyPath;
    }

    IObservable<string> Observe(){
        return Observable.Defer(()=> mq.receive(keyPath).ToObservable() ).Repeat();
    }

    void OnNext(string msg){
        _mq.send(msg);
    }

    void OnError(Exception e){
        // The message queue might not
        // support serializing exceptions
        // or it might or you might build
        // a protocol for it.
    }
}
```

To use it in a fault tolerant way. Note Retry will resubscribe if there is an exception
thrown upstream delivered by OnError

```
new MQRX("users/1/article/2").
    Retry().
    Subscribe((msg)=>Console.Writeln(msg));
```

On the writing side for example you could send a message every two seconds and retry
the subscription to the generator if there is an error. Note there is unlikely to be
an error in Observable.Interval that just generates a message every time interval but
imagine reading from a file or some other message queue.

```
var mq = new MQRX("users/1/article/2");

Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).
    Select((x)=>x.ToString()).
```

Note you probably should use the IObservable Catch extension method rather than
blindly retrying as you might get the same error over and over again.
        Retry().
        Subscribe(mq);

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own UDP to RX wrapper in 30 lines of VB code and it handles timeouts. TCP wrappers would be similar I guess.

```
Imports System.Reactive
Imports System.Reactive.Linq
Imports System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Public Module UDP
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Generates an IObservable as a UDP stream on the IP endpoint with an optional
    ''' timeout value between results.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="timeout"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Function StreamObserver(
                localPort As Integer, 
                Optional timeout As Nullable(Of TimeSpan) = Nothing
                ) As IObservable(Of UdpReceiveResult)

        Return Linq.Observable.Using(Of UdpReceiveResult, UdpClient)(
            Function() New UdpClient(localPort),
            Function(udpClient)
                Dim o = Observable.Defer(Function() udpClient.
                                                                ReceiveAsync().
                                                                ToObservable())
                If Not timeout Is Nothing Then
                    Return Observable.Timeout(o.Repeat(), timeout.Value)
                Else
                    Return o.Repeat()
                End If
            End Function
        )
    End Function
End Module
```

You could do the same for the write side if you needed. Then you just use normal RX techniques for 
serializing your data into UDP frames.

```
new UDP.StreamObserver(8080, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).
        Select( function(udpResult) MyDeserializeFunction(udpResult)).
        Subscribe( sub (result) DoSomething(result), 
                   sub(error) DoSomethingWithError )
```

Comment: What about "If producer or consumer is failed other party should be able to continue producing/consuming" part?

Comment: You want to look at the Catch extension method of IObservable that allows you to resume a failed Observable. However you have to ask yourself is the intermediate MessageBus a persistent queue? If it is UDP for example and the producer loses connection then resumes it will lose packets if the producer in the meantime has transmitted them. If you are using a persistent message queue then depending on your setup you can recover from errors in the consumer/producer and not lose messages.

Comment: An example with persistent message queue is what I'm looking for. Udp and Tcp examples are good to start though.

Comment: I added an new answer with an imagined message queue API. Replace with your favorite message queue api